# Construct sequence of random variables whose expectation converges to ratio

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have two increasing sequences of positive random variables $X_n$ and $Y_n$ which are independent (that is $X_i$ is independent with $Y_j$). Moreover assume that $\mathbb{E}[X_\infty] = a$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y_\infty] = b$, with both $a$ and $b$ finite and strictly positive.

Then, I think thanks to the monotone convergence theorem we can say:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_n]\rightarrow a \qquad \qquad \mathbb{E}[Y_n]\rightarrow b
$$

Now, I would like to construct a sequence of random variables $Z_n$ such that $\mathbb{E}[Z_n] \rightarrow \frac{a}{a+b}$.

Obviously I can not just consider
$$
Z_n = \frac{X_n}{X_n+Y_n}
$$
because then $\mathbb{E}[Z_n] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X_\infty}{X_\infty+Y_\infty}\right] \neq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_\infty]}{\mathbb{E}[X_\infty+Y_\infty]}$ (assuming that the limit can be taken into the expectation).

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Why cant the random variables $Z_n$ be deterministic?

Comment: @clark Because I don't know the values of $a$ and $b$.